# Javascript function, need to decrement every 30 secs time elapsed

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I'm trying to make the `this.SPAWN_FREQUENCY` decrease by 200 after time elapsed reaches 30 seconds, 1 min, 2 min and so on. Basically levels in the game increasing the amount of enemies to defeat. I've tried a load of code and still can't get anything to work.
Any suggestions where to start?
Sorry if I didn't provide enough detail.

```
 function EnemyManager (timer) {
       this.enemies = [];
       this.SPEED = -5;
       this.SPAWN_FREQUENCY = 1300;
       this.spawnTimer = 0;
```

*Do I add 'if' statement?*

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout

```js
     (function () {
            var interval = 1000*30;
           var SPAWN_FREQUENCY = 1300;
            timer = function() {
               
                SPAWN_FREQUENCY = SPAWN_FREQUENCY - 200;
                //do the rest
                console.log(SPAWN_FREQUENCY);
             
                    setTimeout(timer, interval);
     interval = interval*2;
                
            };
            timer();
        })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like:

```
function Manager(){
  this.SPAWN_FREQUENCY = 1300;
  this.inc();
}

Manager.prototype.inc = function(){
   var this_store = this;
   setTimeout(function(){
      this_store.SPAWN_FREQUENCY -= 200;
      this_store.inc();
   }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
var element = this;    
var spawninterval = window.setInterval(function(){
   element.SPAWN_FREQUENCY -= 200;
},30000);
```

and when you're done, you can call

```
window.clearInterval(spawninterval);
```